# Cosa sono "... Gli inesprimibili!"?

Tags: word-meaning, history

Leggendo il bel racconto pieno di ironia "Skating-Ring" della Marchesa Colombi (pseudonimo di Maria Antonietta Torriani, 1840-1920), dalla raccolta "Donne allo specchio" a cura di Guido Davico Bonino, mi imbatto in un'espressione velata che non riesco a... svelare! Potete aiutarmi? 
Vi riporto il brano (a p. 82): il protagonista, inglese di buona nascita ("il mio babbo era membro della Camera dei Lordi") e di bella presenza, avvezzo ai divertimenti nella vita elegante di Londra, dopo aver ereditato un cospicuo patrimonio da uno zio e arrivato ai trent'anni, è spinto da indicazione paterna a procurarsi un erede legittimo. Spaventato dalla vita coniugale e dalla troppa libertà delle signore inglesi...

> "La prima idea che mi s'affacciò alla mente fu d'andare a pigliar moglie in Turchia. Là le fanciulle sono coperte fino agli occhi; nessuno le vede, nessuno le corteggia prima dello sposo. - Ma - c'era un guaio! Le donne turche portano i... come dire? Gli inesprimibili!"

Cosa sono questi inesprimibili?

Comment: Dopo aver letto solo questa breve citazione, non ne ho idea. Non vedo un significato nascosto o un riferimento culturale che potresti aver mancato. Puoi riportare anche il periodo successivo? Forse lì si spiega meglio a cosa l'autrice si riferisce...

Comment: Io mi soffermerei anche sul significato di *Camera dei Lordi*!

Answer (score 11):

Che orrore per un vero e proprio gentiluomo, chiamare le calze le calze...

"Gli inesprimibili" riferiscono a mutande, calze o guepières (La Repubblica: [Se è vietato nominare la guepière](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/2000/03/13/se-vietato-nominare-la-guepiere.html)). Le donne turche portavano qualcosa di questo genere:

[image]
([image source](http://www.algeria.com/forums/womens-corner/15661-turkish-traditional-bridalwear.html))

Ovviamente, nel 1877 questo era il costume dell'estrema libertà di stile, adatto forse per la spiaggia ma non per la vita a Londra:

> Le più modeste *ladies*, che cadrebbero coscienziosamente svenute se il loro marito osasse chiamare col suo vero nome quella parte del loro vestiario che loro definiscono pudicamente *gli inesprimibili*, non esitano a mostrarsi sulla spiaggia, succintamente vestite di inesprimibili anch'esse, lasciando tutta all'estremità delle gambe che ne sporgono... ([*La gente per bene* di Marchesa Colombi, Booklassic, 2015](https://books.google.se/books?id=OpwOCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT127&dq=%22gli%20inesprimibili%22&pg=PT127#v=onepage&q=%22gli%20inesprimibili%22&f=false))

Comment: Il testo della Marchesa Colombi che hai citato si può leggere anche su [Liber Liber](http://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-m/marchesa-colombi-alias-maria-antonietta-torriani-torelli-viollier/la-gente-per-bene/).

Comment: Cool! Grazie mille, @Charo.